# Misprint in Rashi Nozir 45a?

Tags: talmud-gemara, rashi, mistakes, nozir

In the texts that I have seen, [Rashi commenting on the Gemoro in Nozir 45a](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Nazir.45a.3.1?lang=he) says in part:

> והכי משמע אימתי ובא לפני ה' דהיינו במחנה לוייה בזמן שהוא ראוי לבא אל
> אהל מועד דהביא כפרתו הא אם לא הביא כפרתו לא וא"ת והא מצורעין נכנסין
> בשערי ניקנור ששם מזין על הבהמות הא לא קשיא דביאה במקצת לאו שמה ביאה:
>
> And here it means when can he come “before Hashem” that is in the
> Levite camp, when he is fit to go into the Tent of Meeting because he
> has brought his atonement offering. If he has not  brought his
> atonement offering, he cannot enter. And if you will say, but don't
> metzoroim enter through Nikanor Gate which is where they sprinkle on
> the animals, that's not a question because partial entry is not
> considered full entry.

I do not know what is meant by “ מזין על הבהמות"  “they sprinkle on the animals”. It seems to me that it should say “ מזין על הבהונות" (sprinkle on the thumb and big toe) and הבהמות is a misprint.

Am I right or can the existing text be explained?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Moznaim edition found at [HebrewBooks.org](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=17&daf=45&format=pdf) does indeed have the text:

> מזין על הבהונות

It would seem that the version you were looking at contains a misprint.

Comment: More likely than a misprint, it printed out of a manuscript that had the vav touching the nun by accident which looked like a mem. Or maybe the nun touched the following vav and the printer "corrected" בהומת to בהמות.